# Open H2 Database from Classpath

Tags: java, h2

I've seen from the H2 documentation that you [can open files on the classpath](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system).

I've tried various URLs (e.g. `jdbc:h2:classpath:/myDatabase`) when opening a connection, but none seem to find the resource - but when I try `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myDatabase")` it can find it it fine.

The database is on the classpath in `src\test\resources`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Correct format is like this: `jdbc:h2:file:/data/sample`. You can try with relative file name also

Comment: @Ivan ``Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:/data/myDatabase". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-194]
 at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)``

Comment: How do you intend on packaging this? src sounds like it isn't on your class path, but gets put there as a resource when you package/run your program. You shouldn't really expect resources to be writable, but I suspect your database is going to be. So something doesn't line up correctly.

Comment: As an alternative if you can't get this to work (I can't either) you could try an in memory database that just sets up links to the saved database?

Comment: @matt it would be packaged into a single JAR via Maven. The database would be readonly (as in my use case) although I believe H2 falls back to a read only connection if it can't write anyway.

Comment: Did you check this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6507639/2067492 It seems to create a filesystem from the jar file. Have you considered reading the database into memory and creating an in memory database?

Comment: @matt my database is quite large and recreating the database from scratch will be quite slow.

Comment: I don't understand how either of my suggestions cause you to recreate the database from scratch. The first one is nearly exactly what you're asking, http://h2database.com/html/features.html#database_in_zip create a database and save it in a mode that can be used later read-only. It also doesn't load the whole database in-memory.  The in-memory version, I haven't seen a way to do it, so maybe it is always blank and you'd have to re-populate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can locate the `myDatabase` file. When running locally and unpacked, e.g. from inside the IDE you can do:

```
URL res = MyClass.class.getResource("/myDatabase");
String url = "jdbc:h2:" + res.toString();
```

which will output the full resource path e.g. `jdbc:h2:file:/home/.../classes/myDatabase`

This won't work when you package your app as a JAR or WAR. In this case the `myDatabase` will be packaged inside a ZIP archive, to quote [this post](https://markmail.org/thread/26btbp3gmhivxrwt#query:+page:1+mid:w2jum4qheywkqclb+state:results):

> The main problem for both zipped databases and databases in the
>   classpath is: you can't do real random access. You can only read from
>   a stream. Random access is required, so it is simulated like this:
>   When seek(pos) larger than current position, then a skip is made
>   (which is basically a read). If the seek pos is smaller, then the
>   stream is closed and re-opened. This is very slow.

ZIP support is read-only based on [Advanced > Pluggable File System docs](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#file_system):

> zip: read-only zip-file based file system. Format: zip:/zipFileName!/fileName.

You probably should supply the path to the `myDatabase` using command line arguments or system variable and keep it outside of packaged application.

Comment: I am aware of potential workarounds, but if H2 offers the ability to read from a database in the classpath, I would like to try this if possible.

Comment: @Jakg as per the post and explanation I referenced I don't believe there is option to read from classpath. You can resolve the URL to a resource but it might not work when inside a JAR.

Answer (score -1):

this works for me... it creates the pher folder in the classpath and "pharmadatabase" is my database name.
`jdbc:h2:file:pher/~/pharmadatabase;`

you can see the path below-

[image]

Comment: ``Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: A file path that is implicitly relative to the current working directory is not allowed in the database URL "jdbc:h2:file:project/~/myDatabase;". Use an absolute path, ~/name, ./name, or the baseDir setting instead. [90011-194]``

Does this actually work for you?

Comment: yeah it works for me... here is the src code .. you can check out https://github.com/Fathma/PharmacyProject/tree/master/pharmacy   and this is the db connection   https://github.com/Fathma/PharmacyProject/blob/master/pharmacy/src/phar/db.java